# Starting external programme from PHP

Tags: php

I am running in a Windows10 environment. My php script writes a pdf file and I simply want to have the file open up in the pdf viewer that I specify.  I am using the "runAsynchronously" function given in the PHP manual and I have tried many variations.  I have no problem getting the process to run in the background - it appears every time in my TaskManager process listing, but no window appears - what am I doing wrong? If I double click the link file that has been written it works fine.  It is nothing to do with the path to the executable or the filename - I can replace the pdf viewer with "notepad.exe" and the $file with a suitable text file - the same thing happens, notepad appears as a process, but not as a window, and the link works fine.

Here are some code snippets

```
$cmd = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\SumatraPDF\\SumatraPDF.exe";
runAsynchronously($cmd, $file, 7, null, true);

function runAsynchronously($path, $arguments, $windowstyle=1, $lnkfile=null, $exec=true) {
    $tmp = (is_null($lnkfile)) ? 'C:\temp\temp.lnk' : $lnkfile;
    try {
        if(file_exists($tmp)) { unlink($tmp); }
        $WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
        $oShellLink = $WshShell->CreateShortcut($tmp);
        $oShellLink->TargetPath = $path;
        $oShellLink->Arguments = $arguments;
        $oShellLink->WorkingDirectory = dirname($path);
        $oShellLink->WindowStyle = 1;
        $oShellLink->Save();
        $waitforcompletion = false;
        if($exec) {
                // Run kicks off the process in the background, but no window gets opened
                $oExec = $WshShell->Run($tmp, $windowstyle, $waitforcompletion);
                unlink($tmp);
            } // if not executed link is left available for manual running
            unset($WshShell,$oShellLink,$oExec);
        } catch(Exception $ex) {
            print $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Comment: do you know that php is meant for server side scripts ?  IMHO this is program for different language

Comment: @JozefDochan ["PHP is a popular general-purpose scripting language that is especially suited to web development."](http://www.php.net). "General-purpose" being the key phrase there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php How do I start an external program running - Having trouble with system and exec](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403203/php-how-do-i-start-an-external-program-running-having-trouble-with-system-and)

Comment: According to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433973/what-does-the-two-parameters-mean-for-wscript-here you should use 1 when opening a window for the first time, you are specifying windowStyle 7 (minimised)

Answer (score 0):

**If opening in the browser a pdf or downloading it solves your problem, try a class called PDFMerger:**

https://github.com/clegginabox/pdf-merger

It uses an API called setasign FPDI and FPDF (https://packagist.org/packages/setasign/fpdi-fpdf#p-456)
I tested it here, because it also interested me and worked ok. (Wamp in Windows 8.1)

I put everything together(classes and folders of fpdi and fpdf) in a folder called pdfmerger because I was having some difficulty with namespaces and my code worked ok, but I know this is not the best way to include the classes - the example in GitHub page must help if you have problems with classes not finding classes):

```
<?php
include "pdfmerger/fpdf.php";
include "pdfmerger/fpdi.php";
include 'pdfmerger/PDFMerger.php';

$pdf = new PDFMerger();

//generate a pdf with the pages 1,2 and 3 and send to browser
$pdf->addPDF('originalpdfsavedintheserver.pdf', '1,2,3')
    ->merge('browser', 'nameinbrowser.pdf');

// REPLACE 'browser' WITH 'file', 'download', 'string', or 'browser' for output options
```

If you use the option 'download' you can choose the program that will open the pdf file in your windows settings(Choose default program to open pdfs):
https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-set-default-programs-in-windows-10/